# Suppose $Ax = b$ where $b \in \mathbb F^m$ has only one solution when $b = 0$. Show all entries of $A$ is $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix over the field $\mathbb F$.

Suppose $Ax = b$ where $b \in \mathbb F^m$ has only one solution when $b = 0$.

Show all entries of $A$ is $0$.

Why is this true ? $x=0$ is a solution, but if all entries of $A$ is $0$ then there is more than one solution?

Comment: As you point out, this is completely false. Did you copy the claim correctly?

Comment: Directly translated from danish:
Suppose the linear system $Ax = b$, $b \in \mathbb F^m$, alone has one solution when $b = 0$. Show that all entries of $A$ is zero. Do this help ?

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple counterexample to the OP's claim:

$$\binom xy=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\binom xy=\binom 00\iff x=y=0$$.

Thus, either the translation is incorrect or the exercise's dead wrong.

I think the exercise should be: if the only case when the linear system $\;Ax=b\;$ has a solution is when $\;b=0\;$ , then it must be $\;A=0\;$, and this *is true*, since for example

$$Ax=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\ldots\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\;\text{has no solution, so it must be that}$$

$$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\ldots+a_{1n}x_n=1\;\;\text{can't be solved}$$

which is possible only if $\;a_{ij}=0\;\;\forall \,i,j\;$ , etc.

Answer (score 0):

there is another case

$A*x=0$ may have not solution at all besides $x=0$,even if they have one vector  spanning null space of matrix,any  vector given by vector $x$ multiplies by some scalar is also solution,so we  dont   need that matrix be null matrix